# How to remove unoriginal USB cable on the dashboard?

Tags: opel, dashboard

In my Opel Meriva B, I have this unoriginal USB cable going out of the top of the dashboard. It was already there as I bought the car from the previous owner. I never used the cable and I would like to remove it.

Besides the cable, there has to be also some DC/DC converter, since USB uses 5V and the car battery voltage is 12V.

The simplest way would be to cut the end of the cable and leave the rest, but I don't want to risk a short circuit, since the other end would be still connected to the 5V supply.

I would like to remove the whole setup instead, e.g. disconnect the DC/DC converter and pull out the cable. But I don't know exactly where converter is located. It's not visible anywhere. The cable goes out of the trim directly above the infotainment display, so maybe the connection isn't very far from that.

Any ideas how to proceed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It certainly appears that at least some of the dash was disassembled in order to place this cable.  To do a proper job of removing it I believe you're going to have to disassemble the dash yourself and find where it's connected.

You might have some luck crawling under the dash and looking upward (yes, you basically need to get in upside down) and see if you can find where it's attached electrically.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a search for "Meriva B 13277072" or "Meriva B multifunction display" if that is not the correct one on ebay, you will find lots of photos of the multifunction display from different angles.  It looks very much like this unit just clips into the dashboard.  However a lot of the photos show broken off clips like the one below, so it may be a tricky job to get it out without some kind of damage.

Once this is out, it looks like you will have access your cable.

[image]

[image]